# Cv website development problems

Tags: entities

I am trying to achieve something like this http://www.vooshthemes.com/gallery/jamba/ in Drupal.
Its a CV website, what confuses me is how to deal with fields.
If u visit the link i provided above u'll see Experience, Expertise,Education and Training  Category in which u can mention from which year to which year u worked where and what was you task.

My problem is how do i enable the user to add more fields just like in the Cv example page??
i will be using Drupal 7.
any suggestion will be apppreciated.

Comment: Curriculum Vitae (résumé) may be confusing to some.  Re-working your question would likely bring more activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do it, depending on how friendly you want the ui to be and how comfortable you are customising drupal.

I would look at the Field Collection module - http://drupal.org/project/field_collection. It should let you create a group of fields that can be treated as a single field.

ie you could create an 'Experience' field collection consisting of Title, Experience, Duration, Summary and whatever else you need. Then the end user should be able to add multiples of these if you set the field to allow multiple values.

I am saying should because I haven't directly used this module myself, in a similar situation I have created a custom form widget containing the multiple elements. Thats is potentially a more complicated exercise. You could see an example of what might be required there in the Examples for Developers module : http://drupal.org/project/examples

Comment: Thank you very Much, i tried the Field_collection Module and its doing exactly what i need.